# Insert 2times on Database by Method in Asp.net Core

Tags: database, asp.net-core, methods, insert, repeat

I have a method to add user email for Newsletter. It works, but after adding an email it adds it twice. Why?

ViewModel:

```
public string Phone { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Service method:

```
public async Task<NewsLetterResult> AddEmailForNewsLetter(AddNewsLetterViewModel addewsLetterViewModel)
{
    var email = await _newsLetterRepository.EmailExists(addewsLetterViewModel.Email);
    if (email)
    {
        return NewsLetterResult.EmailExist;
    }
    NewsLetter newsLetter = new NewsLetter()
    {
        Email = addewsLetterViewModel.Email,
        CreateDate = DateTime.Now
    };
    await _newsLetterRepository.AddEmailForNewsLetter(newsLetter);
    await _newsLetterRepository.SaveChange();
    return NewsLetterResult.Success;
}
```

Repository:

```
public async Task<bool> EmailExists(string email)
{
    return await _context.NewsLetters.AnyAsync(u => u.Email==email);
}

public async Task AddEmailForNewsLetter(NewsLetter newsLetter)
{
    await _context.AddAsync(newsLetter);
}
```

and its view is the ajax form:

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="NewsLetter" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-success="NewLetterPostSuccess">
    <input asp-for="Email" id="NewsLetterEmail" class="form-control input-textbox-footer" placeholder="@_localizer["EnterEmail"]">
    <span asp-validation-for="Email"></span>
    <button class="btn btn--orange footer__send-btn">@_localizer["SendButton"]</button>
```

Comment: Delete `await _newsLetterRepository.SaveChange();`, and add `await _context..SaveChange();` in `AddEmailForNewsLetter` method.

Comment: Please show your record in db, you can update the image in post.

Comment: I solve this problem ,mistake was about I had reference validation-unobtrusive.I deleted one of them and it becomes correct

Comment: You can post your answer in below, it will help more forum users ^-^.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem ,mistake was about I had referenced validation-unobtrusive.I deleted one of them and it becomes correct

I deleted one of this reference:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-unobtrusive-ajax/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>

enter code here
```